# What to do with Elijah's leftover wine?

Tags: minhag, passover, eliyahu-hanavi

Appears his thirst was quenched by the time he got here. Can I assume he just took a sip and the rest can be shared among the guests? Is it better to wait until everyone is gone so they don't see me polish it off?

Comment: What is Elijah's wine?

Comment: @mekubal is that a trick question? It is the cup of wine poured for Elijah at the Passover Seder.

Comment: never heard of it.  Is it an Ashkenazi thing?

Comment: @mekubal apparently so, at least according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Passover_Seder&section=19#Bareich_.28Grace_after_Meals.29).

Comment: Abe, a question that explains what it's asking about instead of assuming everyone knows everything the asker knows is a much better question.